# RecyclerView jumps directly to top when scrolling up when its item's height is wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Here are the xml files

A `Fragment` with a `Recyclerview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.photos.PhotosFragment"
        tools:listItem="@layout/card_photo">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Layout for each item in the above `Recyclerview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/placeholder_photo_item" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: item_height_wrap_content]

As you can see, it won't load fast and smooth as I scroll. It stops scrolling at some items.
Also when I scroll up, it directly jumps to the top item.

Below is the perfect smooth and fast scrolling effect of a `RecyclerView`, which I am able to achieve by making the `Recyclerview`'s item's (here `CardView`) height to `"match_parent"`.

[image: item_height_match_parent]

But this is not how I want the list to look like. The list should have images of variable length with no blank spaces between them.

Answer (score 4):

I am using `Glide` to load the images, and adding a placeholder through `Glide` fixed it:

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.color.placeholder)
            .into(holder.photo);
```

Now the `RecyclerView` scrolls smoothly and won't jump to the first item on up-scroll.

Although it's been fixed I really do not know why `RecyclerView` behaves in this way.

Comment: Thanks! I had a tangentially related issue where the `RecyclerView` wasn't letting you scroll to the very bottom of the list – the view would jump once you were near the bottom the items.

Adding a placeholder image with `Coil` (rather than `Glide`) ended up fixing this for me. I suspect it's something to do with the RecyclerView re-calculating its scrolling height at different points in its lifecycle.

Comment: This was the fix for me as well -- I am using Picasso. I knew there was an issue with the recyclerview recalculating the height, but I did not know placeholder would work to make it wrap properly and scroll without jumping to the top. Thanks!!